# directed unweighted graphs C

Tags: c, graph, directed-graph

I'm planning to write a program in C that builds the adjacency list, performs the 
depth first search, performs the breadth first search, and performs the 
topological sort.
Where can I get some info about this subject in C? 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: your lecturer or previous years students? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a good algorithms textbook, I'd recommend getting a copy of Robert Sedgewick's [*Algorithms in C, Part 5:  Graph Algorithms.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201316633)

I own the C++ and Java versions of the book, and both are very good.  I *do not* own the C version of the book, so it *might* be atrocious (I doubt it; it's probably very good too).

The *Parts 1-4* book is a good algorithms reference book as well; the material is presented very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, and Clifford Stein is a classic. However, it does not have a specific language approach.

Data Structures In C by Noel Kalicharan if you want a C approach.